# Can a div have one background image, but repeat a different one?

Tags: css, html, background

I'm setting up a design that uses some gradients, and of course that causes issues. What I want is for my one background image with the vertical gradient to be the main background, but then if the content extends and pushes the div out, I want a different sliver image to repeat on the bottom. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is using a background color with your background image. Then set the image to non repeating. Then the color will be the background for the parts of the div where the backgound image is not.

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, but it gives me the idea for how to. Thanks! What I'll do is have the wrapper div contain the repeating sliver, then I can have the divs inside the wrapper put their images over the top and not repeat. that way when the one image is finished, there will be the repeating background image I want. Thanks!